# Motion Blur at different frames

Tags: rendering, animation, motion-blur

I want to render my scene in Blender with Motion Blur enabled, but I don't know whether I'm able to render the whole scene in one rush, for it'll last quite long.

Question: When I start rendering at frame 1 and stop rendering at frame 10, when I start rendering frame 10/11 again will the motion blur look the same or does the interruption cause a change in the blur look of the restarted rendering?

Comment: There should be no issues  as long as you don't change any of the settings for motion blur in between renders.

Comment: Cegaton's comment is close to an answer. What renderer are you using? They handle motion blur differently, this should be included in the coming answer.

Comment: @Leander I'm sorry, I forget almost everytime to tell you I'm using Cycles (for I forget the Internal renderer quite easily).

Comment: Note that you can easily 'fake' motion blur using vector blur and the speed pass in compositing, which is much, much faster but can cause slight visual artifacts. The speed-quality tradeoff is in favor of vector blur for animations, but traditional motion blur for still images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have observed, when motion blur is enabled and Cycles is the renderer, Blender steps back a frame to compute the motion difference between the frame being rendered and the frame that came before - you can see this happening in the info line at the top of the UV/Image Editor when rendering is underway - so long as you leave all settings unchanged Blender should deliver consistent motion blur over whatever frame range you set - alternatively you can add a one-frame "head" and "tail" to your frame range to make sure you definitely get all frames properly rendered across the breaks in your sequence